# what is logic power, signal power and clock power in FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I am measuring power of my design in spartan3e kit. When I use Xpower Analyxer, it shows me some thing like the figure below

[image]

I don't know what is clock power, logic power, signals power and IOs power. And to what I know, power is estimated on a particular cell, not on signals or wires. Am I right?

Comment: Reading that table, it seems you're not right, and that analyzer measures clocks, logic, signals and IO power consumption separately.

Comment: So do you know how many elements contribute to power in VLSI

Comment: all elements. Literally everything that is powered in your chip at least contributes to static power consumption, and everything that is switched to dynamic power consumption.

Comment: (also, the fact that your power consumption is basically only leakage == quiescent current might indicate your design is far from using the FPGA efficiently, but that's only a rule of thumb)